# Synchronize coroutine from incoming messages

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm using Android Kotlin with the SDK 30 and Coroutine 1.4.1.

I have a function that handles incoming messages to display them on my app in a form of temperature measurement. I use CoroutineScope to process the data and save it in the database. These messages are received from a socket.io connection. The problem is that the messages are not displayed in the correct order when a bulk of data is flowing in.

Now I've looked at my nodejs logs and these messages are sent in the correct order so it can't be that.
I'm using a standard Coroutine function.
See below.

```
fun receiveTmps(data){
    CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
        val usersJob = launch {
            usersBg(data)
        }

    }
}
```

Now I know that with Coroutine I can add a join to wait for the job to finish before starting the next one. But because the messages do not come in at once, but flow continuously over a period of 5 to 20 seconds, it is possible that one message is completed faster than the older one. This causes incorrect order.

My question is, is there any way to handle these tasks 1 by 1 while adding multiple jobs to the list?

Any suggestion or idea is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATED:**

From what I read from the documentation you should also cancel the channel after its done. So that's going to be tricky to close the channel when messages are flowing in and since I don't have a clear number of what's flowing in I'm having a hard time defining that to the channel. I have tested several ways but most of the examples doesnt work or are outdated.

This is the most basic working example but it always has a defined repeat.

```
    val channel = Channel<String>(UNLIMITED)

    fun receiveTmps(data:String){
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
            channel.send(data)
        }
    }
    
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {

        launch {
//            while(!channel.isClosedForReceive){
//                val x = channel.receive()
//                Log.d("deb", "Temperature.. "+ x)
//            }

            repeat(3) {
                val x = channel.receive()
                Log.d("deb", "Temperature.. "+ x)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        receiveTmps("10")
        receiveTmps("30")
        // Many more...

        main()
    }
```

Comment: Do you need to process incoming data concurrently or sequntially is enough? If the latter, then use `Channel`. Start only a single coroutine that reads from the channel in a loop and in your `receiveTmps()` just push data to this channel.

Comment: @broot Thanks for your response it is indeed sequential and not at the same time. Because a newer job should not be completed earlier than an older one. The Channel does indeed look promising. Can I also add jobs on the fly while the consumer is busy? I can't find any clear information on this. Thanks in advance. I am definitely gonna implement this.

Comment: `Channel` in such design is just a queue of tasks to run. Yes, while consumer is busy with one task, producers could add new tasks to the cnannel/queue and tasks will wait to be executed. They will be consumed in FIFO order.

Comment: @broot I don't understand the Coroutine Channel or I overthink it to much. I updated the code within the topic, is there something that I am missing?. It does however runs FIFO which I am glad to see.

Comment: Where did you find the info that channels needs to be closed? I may be wrong, but I believe this is not true. Channel is just a queue, it does not hold any real resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to process some events sequentially then typical solution is to create a queue of events and start a single consumer to process them. In the case of coroutines we can use [Channel](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/channels.html) as a queue and launch a coroutine running in a loop that will be our consumer.

I'm not very familiar with Android, so I may miss something, but it should be something along lines:

```kotlin
    fun receiveTmps(data:String){
        channel.trySend(data).getOrThrow()
    }

    fun main() {
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            for (tmp in channel) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

My assumption is that you want to stop processing events when the activity/service will be destroyed, ignoring all temps that are still waiting in the queue.

Comment: it worked like a charm, thank you very much. I do however use "CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch.." because lifecycleScope doesnt seem to work in Service Class. I get undefined. I hope that doesnt take negative changes to the channel.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. The drawback of your solution is that after the service is destroyed, the coroutine will still work in the background: it will process queued events and then it will idle forever, keeping a reference to `Service` and indirectly to all related objects, making impossible to garbage collect them. As a result, it will leak background task and some memory. To fix this, you can place `CoroutineScope()` in a property of the service, use it to launch anything and then `cancel()` it in `onDestroy()` - it should work similarly to `lifecycleScope`.